# Using materials on 3D models created in Blender

Tags: blender, scenekit, 3d-modelling

I want to make a shape that can't be constructed using the SceneKit build in geometry models so I want to use some other 3D modeling program for that. I am interested if those models (created for example in Blender) can act as models that can be created directly in SceneKit. I want to be able to apply materials and change the object's color in code, and want to know beforehand if this is possible with imported models.

I know I can export the model in .dae (Collada file) and like this I can for sure use the model, but can't change its material.

If it is possible to change it in some other way I would appreciate if you could briefly explain how the object should be exported from Blender (in which format).

Answer (score 0):

Actually yes you can change the material in a Collada (dae) format.

The materials are contained in the class `SCNMaterial`.

Here are the methods you can use to access the material:

---

**First you have probably the easiest method of material access:**

`SCNNode.geometry.firstMaterial`

This method gives your the first material that the object is using.

---

**Next you have entire material access:**

`SCNNode.geometry.materials`

This method gives you an `NSArray` containing all the materials that the object is using.

---

**Then finally you have the good'ol name access:**

`[SCNNode.geometry.materialWithName: NSString]`

This method gives you an `NSArray` containing all the materials that the object is using.

---

**And in the apple docs:**

What is `SCNNode.geometry`? Find out [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNGeometry_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SCNGeometry)

Material [access](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNGeometry_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012000-CLSCHSCNGeometry-SW15) and [manipulation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNMaterial_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNMaterial/diffuse).

---

**A side note:**

To actually control the color/image of a `SCNMaterial` you need to use `SCNMaterialProperty`

A `SCNMaterial` is made up of several `SCNMaterialProperty`s.

For more info please read the docs

Comment: Thank you for your help. When exporting models in Blender, is it enough to just create the shape with no textures and without UV unwraping, or should I do that in order to be able to apply those as materials in Xcode? I tried setting the diffuse map of the first material of my object and got error saying that "diffuse is a get-only property". So I am assuming I am doing something wrong before even exporting.

Comment: To set the diffuse use `diffuse.contents`. This "diffuse" can be set to a color, image etc. For more info please visit the apple docs on `SCNMaterialProperty` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNMaterialProperty_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)SCNMaterialProperty).